# Update PHP from 5.5.7 to 7. on CentOS7

Tags: php

I tried many times to update PHP from 5.5 to 7 on CentOS 7 but always unsuccessful. The installation seems always going well but when I checked php-v it is always:

```
PHP 5.5.7 (cli) (built: Jul  5 2017 12:03:23)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
    with Zend Guard Loader v3.3, Copyright (c) 1998-2014, by Zend Technologies
```

Any idea how can I update?

Comment: because you have two php version installed purge/remove php 5.5.7 and than install php 7

Comment: @NullPoiиteя I start by this: sudo yum remove php-cli mod_php php-common, to delete PHP 5.5.7 and then sudo yum install mod_php70u php70u-cli php70u-mysqlnd but still not ok

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Base repository of CentOS has no php7 packages.
You can use remi repo to install php7 on your CentOS 7.

**Why Remi?**

- PHP package installed from remi repo will work as drop-in replacement for your current php5 binaries.
- Remi repo is managed by one of PHP internals
- Why not?

To install the Remi repository, we need to enable the EPEL repository first.

```
sudo yum install epel-release yum-utils
sudo yum install http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm
```

Then Enable php 7.0 (You can use php 7.1+ too)

```
sudo yum-config-manager --enable remi-php70
```

Now it's time to install php7

```
yum install php php-common php-cli php-mysql
```

*Great!!!*
Now you have php7 on your system.  You can confirm with :

```
php -v
```

*Details Instruction on how to setup php on different OS : https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/*

Comment: Still don't understand why users miss the wizard... https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/